# Delphi 11 Alexandria не видит телефон

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Подскажите, почему может не видеть телефон? Стояла версия 10.4 Сидней. Нормально работал с телефоном. В виндовс телефон вижу, режим разработчика и отладка по USB включены... Может что то в SDK настроить надо?
Куда можно еще посмотреть?